# FPGA - IP camera and FPGA

Tags: image-processing, real-time, fpga, ip-camera, stereo-3d

I want to implement a FPGA-based real-time stereo vision system for long range (up to 100m) depth estimation.

I have decided to use IP cameras for this project 
(although I still don't know that is there any other kind of camera proper for this range or not?).

Is it possible to port output of an IP camera to fpga and then perform related image processing? How?

I will be grateful for any information you can provide.

Answer (score 3):

Possible but impractical, and unlikely to work.

Taking input from an IP camera would require your FPGA design to contain a full network stack to make an HTTP request to each camera, download an image, and decode it. This is more of a job for a microcontroller than an FPGA; it will be very time-consuming to implement in hardware.

You are also likely to run into issues because IP cameras tend to be relatively slow, and cannot be synchronized. That is, if you request an image from two cameras at the same time, there is no guarantee that the images you get back will have been taken at the same time.

Don't use IP cameras for this. They're not suited to the purpose. Use camera modules with digital outputs; they're readily available, and likely less expensive than the IP cameras.

Comment: Thank you @duskwuff . What do you mean by 'tend to be relatively slow'.   I could not find camera modules for this large application. Typical camera modules such as ZED camera have maximum range of around 20m.

Comment: Depending on the context and the budget of your project, you can use reflex camera or industrial camera that provide you a way to control acquisition or synchronisation with dedicated wire.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you have a mid-range FPGA .. then I would say your possible options :
- you can capture a single frame at a time from the IP camera .. if it outputs VGA video .. with hsync, Vsync, ...
- if you are working on a Dev. Kit, the FPGA would be interfaced with an SDram, which gives you the ability to save a couple of frames in it (not a whole video for sure)
- you can conduct simple image processing algos with available DSP slices in your Fpga .. if you are working with xilinx, check DSP48e1 or DSP48A1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should think about using Cameras with SDI interface. SDI is a common standard video interface and is designed to work up to 120m, over 75Ohm coaxial cables.

The SMPTE standard ST 425-4 describes the transmission of a stereoscopic camera stream over dual 3G-SDI links in FullHD at 50/60 Hz.

If you are fine with 1080i, then a single 3G-SDI link will be enough (described in ST 425-2).

Answer (score 0):

SDI interface would be the most ideal for long range applications (widely used in television industries). Then depends on your goal you can implement ISP modules and/or transform SDI signals to your desired output protocols (e.g. PCIe) on the FPGA.